# Any way to recover data mobile

Tags: mobile, data-recovery

Last time i installed to my mobile  LG G3 new SW after installation complete i lost all my data (picture's, video, app ).

Now i need to get all data .

Could anyone advice me any program to recover data ??

Comment: Note we do not recommend companies or services here (I edited your question and removed the off-topic part). As for your issue, you'd better look for [good backup software](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup), so you can restore instead of recover.

Comment: Anytime. One more hint (as there're still no answers): You might wish to be a bit more specific on your requirements. I guess the LG G3 runs Android? Which version? Are you looking for free software, or would you also be willing to pay (how much)? Should the software be stand-alone (i.e. work directly on your device), or should it work from your desktop? In the latter case, on what OS? If my guess with Android was right, also see the [backup](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) and [recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) tag wikis at Android.SE.